# Shell cannot find executable when duplicate name deleted from PATH?

Tags: command-line

I have compiled a package named xxx.Now I have deleted the files related with xxx and installed using repository.But if I type command `[root]$ xxx` , the following message is coming

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/xxx: No such file or directory
```

and if I try, `[root]$/usr/bin/xxx -v` It is working.
Where I want to change the installation location.Or I want to create a symbolic link in `/usr/bin/` which points to `/usr/local/bin/xxx`

Answer (score 4):

To speed up path name lookups, the shell keeps an internal cache mapping the short names of commands to their full path name.  This is probably what you are experiencing here.

You can issue the following command to inspect the current cached path for the program:

```
hash -t xxx
```

This will be pointing to the now missing executable.  You can clear the cache for a particular name with the following command:

```
hash -r xxx
```

Note that this problem will only affect shell sessions that executed the command in the old location.  Any new shell sessions should have a clear lookup cache and find the command as expected.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't want to do any of that.
Let me explain why:

`/usr/bin` is where the applications from the repository are installed.
`/usr/local/bin` is where your compiled applications are installed by default.

When you `make && make install` an application, you will need to override the repository application, therefore `/usr/local/bin` is already in your `$PATH` and it *precedes* `/usr/bin` hence it is executed first.

if you type `which xxx` it will still yield `/usr/local/bin/xxx` because it is still there where you installed it. Issue `rm $(which xxx)` or even better, compile the app again but this time issue `make uninstall` as root.

Comment: If I'm reading the question right, he used to have a version of the program built from source in `/usr/local` which he has removed.  The version in `/usr` is a standard packaged version of the program.  I believe the real problem is the shell lookup cache (as I've detailed in my answer).